# Should I create ASP.net web app or ASP.net MVC with ServiceStack?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, servicestack

I have a working ServiceStack application which started off part of my MVC application which contains my Jquery Mobile web site.

The services are growing and I am thinking about moving the ServiceStack code to separate app but not sure whether I should host service stack in an Asp.net web application or in a MVC application.

Are there any benefits down the road if I go one way or the other? In the future I need to introduce authentication for the services, would that be a factor in deciding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would host it on an vanilla ASP.NET host, since it's a more barebones web host than MVC which adds additional (and un-necessary) HTTP Modules and overhead.